Web scraping with selenium and having trouble clicking on links
I'm using selenium to web scrape from this website because it gets blocked when I use beautiful soup.
The link that I want to click is highlighted in the screenshot, and its html code is highlighted on the right when I inspect element.
I copied the xpath for that part of the html code. But then when I try to click the link using link.click() it says that I can't do it because it is a list object. I also can't print it or do anything else with it like .get_attribute('href'). Please let me know if you have any advice for fixing this specific issue or if I should go about it another way!
I tried originally using beautiful soup but the website does not allow that. I also tried printing the link but get issues like I described above. I was expecting to get the text from the link and not an error.

include the code you've tried.  Sounds like you're using findElements which will return an array/list.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Also screenshot is missing

url = "https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/0001768446/0001104659-24-035606/0001104659-24-035606-index.htm"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
driver.get(url)
link = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="formDiv"]/div/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[3]')
print(link.get_attribute('href'))
I get a similar error if I do link.click() or stuff like that
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'get_attribute'

@browsermator I included it as a comment here just now, that is exactly what is happening, what do you recommend?

driver.find_element

I get an error when I do driver.find_element:
NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"/html/body/div[4]/div[2]/div/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[3]/a"}
... All I'm doing is copying the link  for the url and then copying the XPATH, what am I doing wrong? @browsermator

you should use a more targeted XPATH for the element.  Also use proper webdriverwaits with explicit conditions.  Fully path-based XPATH should be avoided.

I get the same error if I copy xpath or copy full xpath, is there a different way to locate it? @browsermator

@browsermator Okay, is it possible it is an issue with the website I am using? On a different website, I followed the same steps as copy the xpath and then did the same code as I have above I was able to get a specific link from the new website. Let me know if you have any ideas of how to work around this? I appreciate the help you've given so much!!

when browsing manually to the site right-click on the element you are trying to locate and choose "Inspect".  Copy/paste a good amount of the markup that includes that element and add it to your question.  (you may want to start a new question at this point) Someone will be able to give you an idea for a locator/waiting strategy.  Also include the code you are trying to use including some before/after code.

@browsermator thank you! I posted a much more detailed question with all the code!!
